# Python - CSV to XLSX converter - semicolons separation instead of columns

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, xlsx

I have this code:

```
for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join(spacedir, '*.csv')):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
            for c, val in enumerate(row, start=1):
                ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value = val
    i = i + 1
    new_name = str(i)
    wb.save(csvfile + new_name + '.xlsx')
```

On the new file i have something like this in one columns:

BLABLABLA;;;;;;;;X;XX;XX;XX;;XX;XX;XX;XX;X

And I need the data to be displayed in columns and not in a single one with semicolons.

How can I fix this?

thanks!

Comment: When you import data in excel you can set semicolon as a delimiter

Comment: Your code (with the slight change open(csvfile, 'r') ) is working on my computer (python3.4) Please give your python version and the contents of a small sample file.

Comment: i handle with more than 50 files at once :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the csv module ',' is the default delimiter. You need to set the delimiter to ';'

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
```